# I need to redirect an old directory to a new directory with web.config

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, web-config, iis-7.5

I'm trying to 301 redirect **Example.com/thepage/** to **Example.com/web/thepage/**
with a web.config file.

Im using IIS 7.5 and i'm working with asp.

I have tried googling and browsing forums, but i'm new to this and haven't found an answer yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have a look [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect) this is the documentation of IIS and here the httpRedirect option in web.config.